# How to conditionally sample a texture in WGSL?

Tags: textures, fragment-shader, wgpu-rs, wgsl

I have a shader with N bind groups for N textures, and I want to sample only one of them at the time in my fragment shader based on a texture index.

Is it possible to do any of the following in WGSL?

1. Bind each separate texture bind group to an element of an array, so I can access the array
2. Conditionally sample only one texture. I tried this one as the example below, and I get a validation error. Also it doesn't seem feasible to maintain this approach if I have a lot of textures.

```
@group(0) @binding(0)
var texture0: texture_2d<f32>;
@group(0) @binding(1)
var sampler0: sampler;
@group(1) @binding(0)
var texture1: texture_2d<f32>;
@group(1) @binding(1)
var sampler1: sampler;

@fragment
fn fs_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    var texture_sample: vec4<f32> = vec4<f32>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    if (in.texture_index == 1u) {
        texture_sample = textureSample(texture1, sampler1, in.coordinates);
    } else {
        texture_sample = textureSample(texture0, sampler0, in.coordinates);
    }
    return texture_sample;
}
```

With this I get:

```
Shader validation error: 
    ┌─ Shader:125:17
    │
125 │         texture_sample = textureSample(texture1, sampler1, in.coordinates);
    │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ naga::Expression [108]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the naga validation error you're getting is about [uniformity](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#uniformity), you have three options for making it compile:

1. Use [textureSampleLevel](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#texturesamplelevel) instead of textureSample, which doesn't have the same uniformity requirements
2. Store your texture index in a uniform variable instead of the vertex output which is a varying value
3. Perform all the texture samples regardless of branch, and just use the branch to choose which sample you want:

```
@fragment
fn fs_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    let texture_sample_1 = textureSample(texture1, sampler1, in.coordinates);
    let texture_sample_2 = textureSample(texture0, sampler0, in.coordinates);

    var texture_sample: vec4<f32> = vec4<f32>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    if (in.texture_index == 1u) {
        texture_sample = texture_sample_1;
    } else {
        texture_sample = texture_sample_2;
    }
    return texture_sample;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it going to be very expensive to do a lot of texture sampling? In my application I will have way more than 2 textures

Comment: if you have a lot of textures then you can try using set_bind_group to specify the texture you will use instead of passing it from the vertex shader (if this is possible for you). If you can't do that, then I guess you'll need to find a way to make your branches satisfy the uniformity analysis.

Comment: I see, it seems textureSampleLevel works best in my case, thank you! However I cannot find much documentation about pros and cons of using textureSampleLevel (with mip level always 0) vs textureSample, or even why that does not have the same uniformity requirements. Do you happen to know?

Comment: Sorry I'm not 100% sure! Would be worth checking on the wgpu matrix channel, somebody there may know the answer: https://matrix.to/#/#wgpu-users:matrix.org. Or maybe look up the answer to the question on the vulkan docs, maybe vulkan has the same restrictions.